# I have trouble with OneDrive

Tags: windows, windows-10, sync, storage, onedrive

I received a 'Continue setting up Windows' prompt on my device. During the set-up, I accidentally synced my PC storage to OneDrive. Whatever I delete in OneDrive is deleted in my PC. My phone is also connected to OneDrive.
My question is if **there is any way to delete OneDrive files without deleting my PC files**. Keep in mind that whenever I move the file to its designated PC folder, it shows 'The source and the file name are the same'. I also want an answer because I do not want to see those little check marks.

***Help me please!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sign Out of OneDrive in Windows 10**

1. Right click the OneDrive icon in the system tray to open its settings.

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oyfY.png)

2. Go to the Account tab and click on Unlink This PC as shown below.

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fatrp.png)

3. The OneDrive app will now be unlinked from this PC. It won't sync files to your OneDrive folder in Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I will try this as soon as I can. I just hope it won't  affect my PC files. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Move the files in question to a location completely outside of (away from) One Drive.

These files will then not be deleted when One Drive is deleted or files in One Drive are deleted.

I prefer this approach to trying to prevent sync in case settings get changed back for some reason.